# Is there a way to share docker application with 3rd party with no visibility to application code

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have to deploy my application using docker on clients machine but i do not want them to access my code how can i do this in docker.

Comment: dont copy the code. just copy your executable jar to docker container and distribute it.  Check docker compose documentation on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Packaging the code inside the Docker container will allow anyone with access to the machine and with the right permissions to go inside the container and view the internal filesystem.

Docker in this case doesn't help you in hiding the code. You need to hide the code just as you would without using Docker.
This depends on the language that you are using. However, one generic way is to just package an executable inside the container.

Alternatively, depending on the lanuage you are using, you can search for a tool to do **code obfuscation** for that language and use this tool when packaging the code inside the container.